# Reformat with awk and sed from STDIN and execute

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

This is just an example of what I run into a lot:
I would like to copy all .bash_histories to one directory.

```
grep "/bin/bash" /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{ print "cp " $6"/.bash_history /backup" $6 ".bash_history" }
```

Output:

```
cp /home/peter/.bash_history /backup/home/peter/.bash_history
cp /home/john/.bash_history /backup/home/john/.bash_history
```

What I would like is an output like this:

```
cp /home/peter/.bash_history /backup/_home_peter_.bash_history
cp /home/john/.bash_history /backup/_home_john_.bash_history
```

And that this output will be executed.

(It's not specifically about this issue, but just in general how to reformat with awk and sed and execute the new created command line, without really creating a script for it)

Comment: What problems are you encountering?

Comment: I want the slashes in the second representation of $6 to be converted to underscores. And I want the newly created cp command to be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getent passwd | grep \/bin\/bash | cut -d ":" -f 6 | while read a; do eval "cp $a/.bash_history /backup/$(echo $a | sed 's#/#_#g')_.bash_history"; done
```

Worked perfectly! Issue solved!

Comment: Glad to hear you can make use of the answer =), sometimes I get criticized for not having enough explanation - you can close the question (by clicking on the Accept Answer link) whenever you are ready.

Answer (score 0):

The awk script to obtain a similar output will be

```
grep "/bin/bash" /etc/passwd |head -2 | awk -F: '{ print "cp " $6 "/.bash_history backup/_home_"$1".bash_history" }'
```

giving an output like

```
cp /root/.bash_history backup/_home_root.bash_history
cp /home/xxx/.bash_history backup/_home_xxx.bash_history
```

Now inorder to excecute the commands, the `system()` function within the `awk` would be helpfull

`system(command)` would excecute any command, and return value being the exit status of the command.

The above script can be modified as

```
grep "/bin/bash" /etc/passwd |head -2 | awk -F: '{ system("cp " $6 "/.bash_history backup/_home_"$1".bash_history;") }'
```

Test run:

```
$ grep "/bin/bash" /etc/passwd |head -2 | awk -F: '{ system("cp " $6 "/.bash_history backup/_home_"$1".bash_history;") }'
$ ls backup/
_home_xxx.bash_history  _home_root.bash_history
```

PS: It is not recommend to create directories in your root folder. So i intentionally replaced `/backup` in your script to `backup`.

Also inorder for the script to be successful, the `backup` folder must be created before hand.

Comment: system! That is the trick I was looking for! For this particular purpose it works perfectly. But second I would like to format $6. Now taking element $1 from awk was sufficient. But in general I would like to do a sed on $6 so I have more flexibility. But thank you a lot! I am really happy with system. Didn't know about this!

Comment: *I would like to do a sed on $6* What kind of flexiblity are you looking for?

Comment: @JakeRoberts if you find the answer you can accept it so that it would be useful for some others. Thank you :)

Comment: I would be pleased to do this. But how and where? :)

Comment: @JakeRoberts Using the tick mark on to the left of the answer. You are allowed to accept only one answer, but vote up any number of answers you find helpful. Thank you and welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

`getent passwd | grep \/bin\/bash | cut -d ":" -f 6 | while read a; do eval "cp $a/.bash_history /backup/$(echo $a | sed 's#/#_#g')_.bash_history"; done`

This uses getent to fetch the passwd file and cut gets the 6th field like your awk statement did, then it reads each entry line by line and builds the string and executes it with eval.